# How to create custom files from tests in Maven

Tags: java, maven, testng

I have a tests writen in TestNG and running through Maven Surefire. In the tests there are lot of database updates and inserts and I want to create a report of which inserts or updates couldn't be performed (because of invalid data, or whatever). For that I would like to create a CSV file where I will track the IDs and exception messages. I want this file to be created in the target directory of my project (and all of the subprojects). How can I obtain the configuration from maven and use the directory to have all things together? I don't want to hardcode the path to file.

Thank you,
Filip

Comment: I don't understand. You run a TestNG test running INSERT or UPDATE, is that right ? So your test should fail when one of these operations fails, no ? And in such a case failures would be reported directly in Surefire test reports, no ? Or you have an issue with the association between test failures and effective operation failures ?

Comment: The problem is, that in this project I work on, the former developers implemented DB migrations with unit tests (please don't ask me why and if I can change it, because I can't). So there are maybe 50 tests and each of them is actually not testing but receiving data from other APIs and storing them into the DB. Sometimes, however, the data are wrong and that results in an Exception which fails the "test". I want to implement a kind of logger for this data and continue with the test, otherwise I will be stuck for years with run the test -> report data error -> run again....

Answer (score 0):

You have to think the other way around: which information should Maven push to/for my test (instead of: how can I pull information from Maven).
One option: create a `test.properties` under `src/test/resources` and add `outputDirectory = ${project.build.testOutputDirectory}` to this file.
In your pom.xml specify

```
<build><testResources>
  <testResource>
    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  <testResource>
...etc
```

Now you can read this file from the classpath and use it in your tests.